# ¿Hay planes para "importar" la herramienta de Documentación a es.SO?

Tags: característica-nueva

[El pasado 21 de julio se lanzó la versión Beta de `Documentation` en StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta?cb=1). En lo personal, me parece una herramienta utilísima para la comunidad.

Una vez superada la etapa Beta en SO, ¿se tienen planes para incluirla en StackOverflow en Español (o en los demás sitios de StackOverflow localizados)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

El 1 de agosto de 2017 Stack Overflow anunció el ocaso de Documentation en [Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/1983854).

Este experimento nunca pasó de la fase Beta público y no consiguió los objetivos que se había propuesto. A saber, conseguir nuevos usuarios para el sitio. Su dificultad de uso y las distintas visiones del producto hicieron que nunca terminara de arrancar.

Hacia el final se vio que podía arreglarse, pero la empresa no creyó pertinente invertir los recursos necesarios para ello y prefirió centrarse en otras líneas del negocio.

Comment: Vi la publicación. Es triste que la herramienta no haya alcanzado la madurez requerida. Espero en el futuro se haga un nuevo intento.

Answer (score 8):

Version corta: ¡Si!

Version larga:

Los planes para traer la herramienta de Documentación a nuestro sitio se están formando pero no sabremos todavía como resultara todo hasta que la cosa haya pasado unos 90 días sin problema en el sitio en inglés. Después de ese tiempo, empezaré a ver con más certidumbre que se necesitará para poder importar esa función aquí.

Comment: Lamentablemente, esta respuesta ya está obsoleta. La respuesta correcta ahora es **No**, como menciona fedorqui

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz cambié ya la respuesta aceptada