# ¿Implementarán Trabajos para desarrolladores en SOes?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, ofertas-de-empleo

Ya sabemos que en un futuro **NO** se implementará la *Documentación* que hubo en SOen y que se acabó cerrando [**(ver información aquí)**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/697/hay-planes-para-importar-la-herramienta-de-documentaci%C3%B3n-a-es-so), pero quisiera saber si tienen pensado implementar la sección de ***"Developer Jobs"***

Pregunto porque estaba navegando en la *Edición de perfil y configuración* y me encontré con este enlace:

[image]

El cual me redirigió a al sitio de ***["Developer Jobs"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)*** en el sitio de SOen

Comment: Jorius, como nota al margen, la documentacion tambien se dio de baja en el sitio en ingles.. mira: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355115/documentation-is-read-only-what-s-next

Comment: @fedorqui: Esta pregunta trata de una consulta sobre una característica por lo que considero que debería incluirse [meta-tag:soporte] en lugar de  [meta-tag:característica-nueva] la cual recién agregaste. ¿Te parece bien si cambiamos las etiquetas mandatorias? P.D. Yo prefiero que las preguntas tengan una sola etiqueta mandatoria.

Comment: @rubén me parece perfecto!

Comment: @Rubén supongo que quieres decir etiquetas obligatorias. Mandatoria no creo que exista, supongo que es un calco de *mandatory* en inglés.

Comment: @blonfu: Al menos hoy día "mandatoria" existe, en mi comentario anterior, luego en tu comentario y ahora nuevamente...mandatoria, mandatoria, mandatoria :P

Comment: Tal vez por "existe" quieres decir que no está registrado en el diccionario de la RAE. De acuerdo a http://dle.rae.es/?w=mandatoria así, es, no está registrada, espero que la agreguen en la siguiente revisión :)

Comment: Vale, existe ;). Entonces digo que la traducción de mandatory sería obligatoria o requerida.

Comment: Considerando que "mandar" si está registrado en el diccionario de la RAE, no veo problema en usar mandatorio/a en un comentario en SOes :)

Comment: @Rubén, creo que no hace falta que lo incluyan, tenemos palabras de sobra: *obligatorio, necesario, forzoso, imperativo, preciso, preceptivo, imprescindible, indispensable, indefectible, pertinente,...*

Comment: @blonfu: No creo que a la RAE le preocupe que el idioma sea "eficiente", si fuera así, no permitirían los sinónimos ni los homónimos

Comment: Sólo era un comentario. No quería crear un debate sobre el idioma en una pregunta que no tiene nada que ver con eso. Mandatorio mola XD

Comment: La respuesta a esta pregunta es igual a la de esta otra pregunta "¿Ganaría SO dinero implementando la sección Developers Jobs en español?"

Comment: Gerva.. estamos esperando ;P

Comment: Después de darle varias vueltas al asunto, haría la siguiente pregunta: ¿vale la pena? Esto debido a que en la pagina de `/Jobs` veo publicados empleos para México, Argentina, España (por mencionar algunos). Talvés de monento lo único que falta es más difusión al sitio de [/Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) y ya cuando el volumen de empleos, tráfico de la página excedan los límites esperados entonces pensar en alguna otra estrategia como implementar Jobs en español, o portugués. Algo así como pasó con el sitio principal que fue segmentado por idiomas ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No me gustaría otra cosa más que poder proveer /jobs en nuestro sitio con trabajos para nuestra gente.

Pero, para poder llegar a eso, necesitamos como empresa el tener un equipo de ventas exclusivamente orientada al mercado hispano-parlante.  Sé que los números validan una decisión de esta magnitud pero por razones legales, corporativas, y de visión interna, no se ha llegado a un acuerdo todavía.

Pero, sigo con la intención de pedir esta función para nuestros sitios internacionales (con más entusiasmo para el nuestro) porque sé que es algo que ayudaría a nuestros desarrolladores. En fin, por ahora sigue la respuesta un "No" pero sigo yo con la mentalidad de "No, pero en un futuro sí."

Sigamos creciendo nuestra comunidad y proporcionando la más alta calidad de información y así la decisión de si se debe traer /jobs a SOes será una decisión lógica.