# Grupo de Traducción - La charla

Tags: discusión, traducciones

Esta pregunta esta [basada en esta encuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3037/grupo-de-traducci%C3%B3n-te-interesa/). Lo que tratamos aquí es el enlace a la sala de chat y la petición de preguntas de nuestros usuarios que traten sobre el formato y el funcionamiento de las traducciones de esta comunidad.

Les pido que hagan preguntas aquí para poder contestarlas durante la charla. Estará [g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) conmigo contestando preguntas en la sala de chat.  Tengo cosas que compartir con ustedes pero también quiero darle tiempo a sus preguntas así que pónganlas aquí.

Empiezo yo con unas que nos hizo [Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano).

La charla tomará lugar el jueves 25 de enero a las 4pm GMT (10am en México, 11am en Colombia, 1pm en Argentina, 5pm en España) en la siguiente sala de chat:

> **[Hablemos sobre las traducciones](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72224/hablemos-sobre-las-traducciones)**

Answer (score 3):

Estas preguntas las hizo [Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano) en [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3041/83).

1. ¿Por qué estamos haciendo una publicación para sumar voluntarios que tengan que responder acá para entrar? Esto me parece que tiende a desanimar a algunos. Hagamos un FAQ para que cualquiera, en cualquier momento, pueda sumarse, sin tener que exponerse en una publicación en Meta. Creo que la misma interfaz de Transifex te permite solicitar el ingreso (sin tener que publicar en Meta o enviar mails). Podemos tomar como ejemplo a [*Mil tradutores são melhores que um*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2705/53463).
2. ¿Qué solución se le puede encontrar para reconocer en Transifex a todos [los textos no implementados aún en el sitio](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/62056?m=38733269#38733269) (que incluso pueden nunca ser implementados)?
3. Si bien la lista de "[*Falta traducción*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)" ofrece enlaces a donde se encuentran los textos, ¿se implementó o se piensa implementar alguna herramienta dentro de Transifex para mostrar el contexto de cada término?
4. ¿Podemos tener [un bot](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4240/53463) que nos avise de cada nuevo texto en Transifex?
5. El cuello de botella suele ser la aprobación de los términos (sólo mods). ¿Tenemos alguna alternativa para evitar este problema? Y si no existe, ¿no es más alto el costo de oportunidad de seguir usando recursos de empleados de SE en todos los sitios internacionales versus el desarrollo de algún tipo de revisión por los usuarios?
6. ¿Vamos a solucionar Transifex pero no los textos hardcoddeados que no estén en Transifex? ¿Cómo hacemos para documentar un procedimiento oficial para traducir estos textos?

Comment: ¡Qué hincha .......! ¿Por qué tiene que preguntar tanto?

Comment: ^^^ es un tipo verdaderamente y verbalmente dotado

Answer (score 2):

Existen tres tipos de textos por traducir:

1. los que están en Transifex
2. los que están hardcoddeados
3. los que pertenecen a ámbito de documentación ([páginas de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help))

---

Sobre el tipo 1 (los que están en Transifex) considero que el método que seguíamos con Konamiman funcionaba bastante bien: un empleado de SE tiene acceso a Transifex e incorpora los cambios que se van sugiriendo en [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/83/83) y [¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/40/83). Fácil, rápido y sin necesidad de herramientas externas para llevar la contabilidad. Entiendo que con unos pocos minutos semanales hay más que suficiente para tener la lista limpia.

**¿Podríamos considerar tener una pregunta por petición de traducción, en lugar de añadir respuestas a la misma pregunta?** [Comentó g3rv4](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42352341#42352341) que resultaría más fácil de filtrar.

---

Sobre el tipo 2 (*los que están hardcoddeados*) [g3rv4 explicó](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42352635#42352635) que para que pasen a ser del tipo 1 (*los que están en Transifex*) el cambio que tiene que hacer es del tipo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, añadir el bloque `@_s(" ")` alrededor de la cadena hardcodeada. Con ello y algún elemento de continuous integration que Stack Exchange tiene configurado, se consigue que Transifex coja la cadena dada y permita que se pueda traducir y enseñar traducida en las páginas SO.es, SO.pt, etc.

El problema es que el texto *Where to find us if you're looking...* sigue presente en el código fuente y cualquier pequeño cambio en él implicará una nueva entrada en Transifex y, por tanto, la pérdida de la traducción existente en esa sección hasta que alguien traduzca la nueva.
<sub>Ejemplo: Si en lugar de *Where to find us if **you're*** se dice *Where to find us if **you are***, la traducción deja de aparecer.</sub>

Todo este rollo para preguntar: **¿podría implementar Stack Exchange algún mecanismo para detectar cuando estas entradas son modificadas?**

Y por supuesto, desde aquí mi agradecimiento a [g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) por estar realizando pull requests con los que convierte estas cadenas y permite que se puedan traducir. Es decir, por mover las cadenas de "2" a "1".

---

Sobre el tipo 3 (*los que pertenecen a ámbito de documentación*).  Se trata de páginas de ayuda y apenas un par de ellas las [pueden modificar los moderadores](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2775/1674); en concreto, la de on-topic). [El resto de páginas solo las pueden modificar los mods empleados](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42310193#42310193). **¿Se podría dar permiso a los moderadores para modificar todas las páginas de ayuda?**

Comment: Cómo funcionaría "un mecanismo para detectar cuando estas entradas son modificadas"? tendría que detectar cambios que no hacen al significado de la oración? o decís algo que diga "la cadena X_english es ahora Y_english. X_english se traducía como X_spanish". Ambos me parecen muy difíciles de implementar [por la forma en la que funciona la extracción](https://mattjibson.com/blog/2013/03/01/careers-localization-part-3-extraction/)

Comment: @g3rv4 para las cadenas ya presentes en Transifex, el apaño fácil que se me ocurre es hacer un dump de todas las cadenas y hacer un `diff` con la versión anterior.

Comment: cómo comparás qué cadenas cambiaron? cada una tiene un hash... así que saber las que no cambiaron es fácil... ahora tenemos cadenas que están en la versión nueva que no están en la versión vieja... y cadenas que desaparecieron en la versión vieja... cómo sabemos cuáles fueron modificaciones y cuáles son realmente nuevas?

Comment: @g3rv4 el `diff` puede contenter el hash pero también el texto al que representa. Entonces, si hacemos el `diff` solamente de las cadenas y las tenemos ordenadas podemos tener una vista como la de [cualquier revisión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3076/revisions). Se me ocurre que seguramente hay alguna herramienta que sabe _leer_ e interpretar ese diff.

Comment: @Mariano hacer un dump de los nuevos términos se puede :) lo que no se puede es decir "donde antes decía `Where to find us if you're` ahora dice `Where to find us if you are`"

Comment: @g3rv4 Por un lado, sabemos que hay forma de ver las cadenas nuevas, por ejemplo el bot que tenía PT.SO en http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27048/traducao-do-sopt, por otro lado, se maneja el contexto de cada término (en [*Falta traducción*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)) está el enlace en el sitio. Falta unir estos datos con lo que haya desaparecido de cada contexto (la página de SOes) y tenerlo todo en algún lugar.

Comment: @g3rv4 sí, terminé de entender y borré el comentario anterior... A lo que me refiero es que no necesariamente tiene que ser 1 a 1, sino por contexto... Ej: en esta página desaparecieron A, B y C, y aparecieron D, E, F, G y H

Comment: @Mariano bien visto. Seguramente uniendo todas estas piezas se pueda obtener una solución que nos lleve a ver todos los cambios.

Comment: @Mariano y ahí tenemos otro punto interesante... no es tanto "en esta página" sino "en esta vista" o "en este archivo de js", cosas que pueden ser claramente útiles para el contexto.

Comment: @g3rv4 entiendo. Igual "*en esta vista/js + link*" le sigue ganando a "*fa2ead697d9998cbc65c81384e6533d5*" :-)

Comment: @Mariano 200% de acuerdo :)

Comment: Interesante, recibí un voto negativo aquí :O

Answer (score 2):

Transifex actualmente está plagado de cadenas que pertenecen al proyecto Documentation, que [murió](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2656/83).

Dado que generan mucho ruido en la sección de cadenas [*Untranslated*](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/79865661?translated=no) (no traducidas), ¿se podrían ignorar de alguna forma, ya sea con alguna funcionalida de Transifex, ya sea pidiendo que el *codebase* del proyecto se quitara de la pipeline que conecta con Transifex?

En particular, **¿se podrían utilizar las [tags](https://docs.transifex.com/translation/tools-in-the-editor#tags) de Transifex al definir las cadenas y así facilitar el filtrado?**

Comment: Lo explicaste mejor con el ejemplo, pero es lo mismo que [mí pregunta 2](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3072/127)

Comment: @Mariano oh, cierto. Si te parece, lo dejo pues me parece el caso paradigmático y el que más explica la situación que expusiste.

Comment: Sí, más bien! Además, no es la misma respuesta a Documentation (que quizás se podría sacar) que lo que se puede responder a Jobs, que no se puede sacar pero que estaría bueno poder identificar en Transifex... Puse el comentario para que las respondan juntas ;-)

Comment: @Mariano por lo que veo, el buscador permite filtrar por _tags_, que [están documentadas en Transifex](https://docs.transifex.com/translation/tools-in-the-editor#tags): _Tags let you group a set of strings within a resource in any way you like. For example, you can use tags to specify where certain strings came from, or prioritize strings for translation using a tag called "Urgent."_. Por tanto, vendría a ser una [meta-tag:feature-request]: ¡usad _tags_ en Transifex!

Comment: groso! ¿Te parece agregarlo en esta pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que un tema interesante, pero que tal vez sea demasiado extenso para ver en una sola charla, es el de los criterios de traducción. Los otros días entré a Transifex y algunos textos me hacían dudar, en que forma era mejor traducirlos, por ejemplo:

- **`Hot Network Questions`**: ¿Respetamos la capitalización de todas las palabras? `Hot` ¿Cómo la traducimos? ¿Cómo `Calientes`, `"Calientes"`, `En el candelero`, `importantes`, etc. ?
- Textos que en algunas latitudes funcionan mejor en inglés: Por ejemplo `"Chat"`.

Esto es solo a modo de ejemplo. En resumen, sería bueno conversar acerca del  mecanismo para la discusión de estos criterios y sin duda la forma en la que documentarlos.

Comment: Por un lado está lo que ya se tradujo, por ejemplo "HNQ" está en todas las páginas de SOes como "Preguntas populares en la red"... Y por otro, en Transifex hay un [glosario](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/glossary/es/) para esto mismo (que prácticamente no se utilizó hasta ahora) y que se podría completar

Comment: Es importantísimo... el otro día entré para revisar traducciones pendientes y encontré algunas que me parecieron muy malas (al estilo de google translate)... terminé traduciendo yo. Si hay ruido en Transifex, hace el proceso de traducción muy ineficiente.

Comment: @Mariano, sin duda "Populares" esa el mejor término para "Hot", me lo había olvidado.

Comment: En relación a "Hot Network Questions" parte del "atractivo" de Hot como pasa con chat y FAQ es que es son monosílabos fáciles de pronunciar, sin embargo me parece que Hot no es usando cuando se habla "correctamente" en español.

Comment: Creo que no está bien hot porque la h no se pronuncia.